# Stripe w/ Ruby on Rails ENV variables in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, stripe-payments

I am not sure how to place my Publishable key into my JavaScript code.  When I place the publishable key's value directly into the JavaScript it works fine.  When I try to use Environment variables It does not work.

config/initializers/stripe.rb

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
  :publishable_key => ENV['PUBLISHABLE_KEY'],
  :secret_key      => ENV['SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

javascripts/charges.js.erb

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey(<%= Rails.configuration.stripe[:publishable_key] %>);

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
  var $form = $('#payment-form');

  if (response.error) {

        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {

        var token = response.id;

        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));

        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
};

jQuery(function($) {
    $('#payment-form').submit(function(e) {
      var $form = $(this);


      $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

      Stripe.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);

      return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

Not exactly a solution but I like the Railscast way (http://railscasts.com/episodes/288-billing-with-stripe) of setting the meta tag with an Environment variable and then using Javascript to call upon the value in the meta tag. The bit you want starts at about 4m10s

```
<%= tag :meta, :name => "stripe-key", :content => STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY %>
```

Then the JS code is:

```
Stripe.setPublishableKey($('meta[name="stripe-key"]').attr('content'))
```

I'm not a fan of inserting environment variables into JS directly.

Comment: Why do you not like inserting environment variables in JS directly?  I am still new, would be nice to know the reason for doing so.

Comment: One reason why it's better not to store keys etc. in the javascript source is that you have to recompile the asset when an ENV variable changes. If you store it in a `meta` tag you just need to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks like it should work. When you start your server are you entering in the proper keys?

PUBLISHABLE_KEY=pk_####_################ SECRET_KEY=sk_####_################# rails s

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't think storing Stripe details in Javascript is wise, you can use a [**gem called `gon`**](https://github.com/gazay/gon) to load variables into JS:

```
#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
gon.push({
  :user_id => 1,
  :user_role => "admin"
})

#app/assets/javascripts/your_javascript.js
gon.variable_name
```

You must add this to your layout file:

```
<head>
  <title>some title</title>
  <%= include_gon %>
  <!-- include your action js code -->
  ...
```

---

To load ENV variables even in development, I would then use a [gem called `Figaro`](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) which basically allows you load ENV variables in any state:

```
#app/config/application.yml
YOUR_ENV_VAR: 'information'
```